# Why is the internal representation of a React element returned instead of the React element itself in the console?

Tags: reactjs, element

```
    function TestComponent(){
        const test = ()=> {
            return <div>
                <h1 class="text-white">halo word</h1>
            </div>
        }
        console.log(test());
        return(
            {test()}
        )
    }
```

In the above component, I expected the rendered **div** to appear in the console log which is calling `test()` but it shows `{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'div', key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}`
How can I solve this?

Comment: What is there to solve? You are logging a React element, not a HTML element.

Comment: The html element is created somewhere in internal function of react, you won't get it

Answer (score 0):

That is because React uses a so-called "virtual DOM" and it is only rendered as an actual DOM in a second step. If you really need to log the actual DOM, try using `renderToString`:

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

console.log(renderToString(<div>hello</div>));
```

or in your case:

```
console.log(renderToString(test()));
```